# ¿Como paso parámetros de javascript entre métodos o funciones?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi problema es que actualmente en mi `$( document ).ready` inicio una variable que es timer y dicha variable al darle clic en un boton debe de modificar su valor a un uno, eso suena muy sencillo, pero lo que quiero es que esa variable se use en otro lado con un valor diferente cuando se de clic en el boton indicado.

Codigo de javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function hola(tiempo) {
  tiempo=1;
  alert(tiempo);
}

</script>
```

Codigo html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(timer);
  if (timer==1) {
    </script>
<div class="wrapper" style="height:50%;margin-top:-5%;" >
      <div class="cell">
        <div id="holder">
          <div class="digits"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  }else {



  }

</script>
```

codigo del document.ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var timer=0;
  alert(timer);
});

</script>
```

Todo se encuentra en un mismo archivo, pero solo me manda el mensaje de cuando carga el timer, pero los demas mensajes ya no me los manda.

codigo del button

```
<button id="btncomprar" class="btn btn-success" onclick="hola(timer);" href="#animatedModal10">
```

Comment: como sugerencia la etiqueta `<script>` no funciona de la misma manera que la de php `<?php ?>`, que esta ultima puede continuar un `if` después de haberse cerrado

Comment: Me parece o estas combiando <script> con <html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dijo Ivan More Flores, parece que estás mezclando *HTML* con *JavaScript* dentro de tu proyecto. Para poder ingresar *JavaScript* en tu *HTML*, debes usar la etiqueta `script` con el atributo `type="text/javascript"`.

Lo más correcto sería tener un archivo *Javascript* en donde escribas tu código y luego lo cargues dentro de la etiqueta `<head>` de tu *HTML*.